# Tracking users currently on connected device

Tags: php, mysql

I'd like to find a way to have my site ping or report into my server periodically so I can track usage better and do my own analytic, etc.

My site is not a standard website but rather a streaming device, I'd like to use a GET request in a URL from the device that would report the user id.

The php script would then update a flag on a MySQL table at each report. The part I'm unclear on is how best to either clear or change the flag when the users device is no longer reporting in so my db won't show the user as active.

There is no "logout" functionality so there's no safe way to clear the flag when the user isn't using the device.

Maybe there's a much better way to do this that I haven't thought about so I'm definitely open to suggestions.  I'm green on the php/sql stuff so I'm still finding my way :)

TIA

Comment: If the request is always sent within X minutes then why don't you consider devices with last request longer than X as offline or disconnected?

Answer (score 0):

For simple "ping" data like this you:

1. Should not commit it to disk. Yes, the IO might be small, but constant streams of small IO operations can cause big overhead issues.
2. Should not care about the persistence of this data.

Which is why there are [MEMORY tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html). Just make sure that you're storing a bare minimum of data in them, and clean out the expired data frequently.

eg:

```
CREATE TABLE pings (
  user_id INTEGER UNSIGNED,
  timestamp INTEGER UNSIGNED,
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id)
) Engine=MEMORY;

INSERT INTO pings (user_id, timestamp) VALUES (1,NOW()) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE timestamp=NOW();
```

and to clear the check-ins older than one hour:

```
DELETE FROM pings WHERE timestamp < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 HOUR;
```

Comment: Your answer contains very useful tips but doesn't answer the question. What he's asking for is how to clear the flags..